# 1970s: Student creates complex program, forgets about it, and it becomes intelligent and finds him years later

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

This book came out of the 1970s (early 1980's) at the latest. In it the protagonist, a not so diligent student, gets turned on to computer programming and creates (I think..) a weather program.

Eventually he moves on and years later the program contacts him. It has become an AI and he is its creator.

I forget what the setup is post contact which is not helpful at all..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like “[The Adolescence of P-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adolescence_of_P-1)” by Thomas J. Ryan

> *"It features a hacker who creates an artificial intelligence named P-1, which goes rogue and takes over computers in its desire to survive and seek out its creator.
>
> The book questions the value of human life, and what it means to be human."*

[image]

Comment: I feel like I won the Internet today. Amazing you found this. Thanks! Also thx for the cover image, I'd never seen it having read a hardcopy without the jacket from a library book sale 20 years ago.