# War Games-like movie on PBS between 1980 and 1996. Protagonist is teenager named "Hacker"

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

So 'Hacker' writes a program which then starts re-writing itself inexplicably.  It becomes conscious.  It creates a voice for itself.  Authorities are chasing Hacker and his girlfriend all over the city.  I don't think the program was evil, just mis-understood.  At some point I think the program called Hacker on a payphone.  That is all I can remember.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't Wargames? That features a teenage hacker and a payphone scene as well as a scene where the computer phones the protagonist

Comment: There's also a scene where David gives the program a voice with a voice simulator

Comment: It wasn't Wargames.  This computer asked the kid to hook up a speaker and the computer sampled the kid's voice and so it sounded like the kid.  I don't think nukes were a factor in the movie.

Comment: To the person who edited: you can add an answer. Commenting takes 15 reputation.

Comment: Steve, instead of editing your own post, mark the correct answer as "accepted".

Comment: @Steve you're unable to mark the answer as accepted as you appear to be using a different account to the one that asked the question.

Comment: I don't know how old this post is. I stumbled on it because I was looking for the name of that PBS film. About that film, was the girl kind of like a "Goth" chick? With her face painted white for some reason? Cool.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/1970s-student-creates-complex-program-forgets-about-it-and-it-becomes-intelli (about the book on which this film may have been based)

Answer (score 8):

Building on Nico's answer above, it  sounds like you're describing "[Hide and Seek](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0256073/)", a 1984 made-for-TV film based on the short story [The Adolescence of P-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adolescence_of_P-1)

> *"A hacker...creates an artificial intelligence named P-1, which goes rogue and takes over computers in its desire to survive and seek out
>   its creator..."*

As you can see from the (bad) screencap below, the computer creates a voice by listening to the hero's phone calls and sampling them. Although the character's name is **Gregory**, he's certainly referred to as a "hacker" within the film and there is also a scene where he uses a payphone.

[image]

You can view the trailer below.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is the TV adaptation of [The Adolescence of P-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adolescence_of_P-1).
It predate War Games as [Hide and Seek](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0256073/)